# Assign S4 slot within loop

Tags: r, r-s4

How can assign values for S4 slot, based on predefined lists?

B1 class created as:

```
mySlots <- c("myA", "c")
myTypes <- c("numeric", "character")
myVals <- c(1222, "blabla")
  
mySlotTypes <- setNames(as.list(myTypes), as.list(mySlots))
mySlotValues <- setNames(as.list(myVals), as.list(mySlots))
    
setClass("B1",
    do.call("representation", mySlotTypes)
)
```

Manually slot can assign with:

```
> x <- new("B1")
> x@myA <- 2333
> x@c <- "ddd"
> str(x)
Formal class 'B1' [package ".GlobalEnv"] with 2 slots
  ..@ myA: num 2333
  ..@ c  : chr "ddd"
```

I tried two options:

**Option A**

Trying to assign with prototype:

```
  setClass("B1",
                 do.call("representation", mySlotTypes),
                 do.call("prototype", mySlotValues)
  )
```

what gave error:

*Error in makePrototypeFromClassDef(properties, ClassDef, immediate, where) :
in making the prototype for class “B1” elements of the prototype failed to match the corresponding slot class: myA (class "numeric" )*

**Option B**

Tried with initialize method without luck as well:

```
  setMethod("initialize", signature  = "B1",
    definition = function (.Object) {
        for(i in slotNames(.Object)) {
            do.call("<-", list( str_c(".Object@", i), mySlotValues[[i]]))
         }
    return (.Object)
    })
```

This solution doesn't gave error, but not initalized at all:

```
>   x <- new("B1")
>   str(x)
Formal class 'B1' [package ".GlobalEnv"] with 2 slots
  ..@ myA: num(0) 
  ..@ c  : chr(0)
```

Is there any simple solution, how can replace the manual `.Object@myA <- 1222` call with loop friendly assignement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the `?slot` help page (linked from the `?"@"` help page), it appears you can do something like this:

```
slot(.Object, i) <- mySlotValues[[i]]
```

Generally concatenating code as a string (as you've attempted with `str_c(".Object@", i)`) doesn't work unless you use `eval(parse(...))`, on the resulting string. This is best avoided. (In this case since you're assigning to the parsed string, you'd further need to use `assign()` or include the assignment as part of the string.)

Your `do.call` is a good idea and is pretty close. It would probably also work if you used the function `"@<-"` instead of just `<-`. Assigning to indices/items/slots have their own functions combining the accessing operator (like `$`, `[`, `[[`, `names()` or in this case `@`) with the assignment. Using `do.call` on the `@<-` function would look like this, and would also work, but it's a bit harder to read.

```
do.call("@<-", list(object = ".Object", name = i, value = mySlotValues[[i]]))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for proper answer and explanation! Nice tricks and it works!